# Why is [Ni(en)3]2+ paramagnetic?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, coordination-compounds

I could not find a satisfactory answer for the above question anywhere on the internet/on SE. Why does $\ce{en}$, which is a strong field ligand, not cause the electrons to pair up in $\ce{[Ni(en)3]^2+}$ the same way it does in $\ce{[Fe(en)3]^3+}$ or $\ce{[Co(en)3]^3+}$?

Comment: See this one https://www.toppr.com/ask/question/nicl2pch332-is-a-paramagnetic-complex-of-niii-analgous-pdii-complex-is-diamagnetic-how-many-geometrical/. The only problem is they mix up CFT and hybridization.

Comment: @M.Farooq that answer is for $\ce{[Ni(Cl)2(PPh3)2]}$ which is tetrahedral and not for the complex in question.

Comment: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/35081/can-a-high-spin-complex-be-diamagnetic?r=SearchResults&s=1|61.1726